# How to JOIN table ON .. LIKE ... 'table.variable'

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

I have two tables and I am trying to JOIN them and use the LIKE function on mySQL.

My initial code was :

```
select A.column
from A
join B
  on (B.column) like ('%A.column%');
```

then I searched stackoverflow past answers and I found that my version was not wrong and at the same time I found this version which did not work either:

```
select A.column 
from A
join B 
  on B.column like '%'+ A.column +'%';
```

In the end I used this one :

```
select A.CPM , B.column , A.column 
from A
join B 
  on B.column like concat('%', A.column,'%');
```

and it worked. My question is why didn't the previous versions work? Is it because of mySQL version? From my research the syntax is correct in all 3 versions. The results on mySQL for the first two were blank though.

Comment: First is just `string literal` second use `+` which is not for string concat, last is build in runtime. That's why the last works.

Comment: @lad2025 What is wrong with the second one?

Comment: `+` is not for string concatenation but for addition.

Comment: `SELECT '%' + 'a' + '%'` => 0 Using `+` my slq tries to convert to numbers and compute sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First: Won't work**

```
select A.column
from A
join B
  on (B.column) like ('%A.column%');
```

Reason:

This is just string literal, hardcoded value

```
B.column LIKE '%A.column%'
```

**Second: Won't work**

```
select A.column 
from A
join B 
  on B.column like '%'+ A.column +'%';
```

Reason:

`+` is not for string concatenation but for addition. Example:

```
SELECT '%' + 'a' + '%' -- result 0, mysql tries to convert to numbers and compute sum.
```

**Third: Will work**

```
select A.CPM , B.column , A.column 
from A
join B 
  on B.column like concat('%', A.column,'%');
```

Reason:

You build last value at runtime using correct function `CONCAT`

Answer (score 1):

In MYSQL `Like` is a string comparison function.

`LIKE` operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column not column matching.

In above two example you are matching with column. In last one you first convert column into string and then apply like.